# In Moment.js is there a better way to get isPM?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My moment.version = 2.10.6.  From what I understand in that version, this is about the smallest amount of code I need to determine AM/PM:

```
// AM
var m = moment("2018-05-16 11:59:59 GMT-0600");
m.localeData().isPM(m.format('A')) // false

// PM
var m = moment("2018-05-16 12:00:00 GMT-0600");
m.localeData().isPM(m.format('A')) // true
```

Is that correct?  If so, it seems a little overcomplicated to me.  I **wanted** to do something like:

```
moment("2018-05-16 11:59:59 GMT-0600").local().isPM()
```

I thought it would be reasonable to expect that `local` would be able to access `localeData` internally and `localeData` would know how to format the string internally for the AM|PM, and therefore the return value of `local` could have an `isPM` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to check for PM:

```
function isPM(momentObj) {
    if (momentObj.format('A') === 'PM')
        return true;
    return false;
}

isPM(moment('2018-05-16T18:00:00')); //true
isPM(moment('2018-05-16T10:00:00')); //false
```

You can also extend `moment.prototype` and implement `isPM`:

```
moment.prototype.isPM = function() {
    if (this.format('A') === 'PM')
        return true;
    return false;
}

moment('2018-05-16T18:00:00').isPM(); //true
moment('2018-05-16T10:00:00').isPM(); //false
```

Comment: One-liner: `let isPM = m => m.format('A') === 'PM';`

Comment: it wont work for other language like hungarian, chinese